# what is the map/flatmap function used in for comprehensions?

Tags: scala, flatmap

I want to see the `f` function that is getting passed in map/flatmap, but no luck. I threw an an exception to see any sign of `f`, did not work. What is that function? how is it generated behind the scenes?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
   at x.x.Main$A.getInt(Empty.scala:8)
   at x.x.Main$A.flatMap(Empty.scala:10)

object Main extends App {

  class A {
    def getInt: Int = throw new RuntimeException
    def map(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(getInt)
    def flatMap(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(getInt)
  }

  for {
    x <- new A
    y <- new A
  } yield x == y
}
```

Comment: It looks like **senia** actually has a better solution for desugaring things in the repl than I do. Maybe you should accept their answer over mine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equivalent code for your for-comprehension

```
for {
  x <- new A
  y <- new A
} yield x == y
```

is like this:

```
new A().flatMap{ x => new A().map{ y => x == y } }
```

You could use `scalac -Xprint:parser main.scala` to get code generated from your `for-comprehension`. In this case you'll get this:

```
new A().flatMap(((x) => new A().map(((y) => x.$eq$eq(y)))))
```

You could also get it in REPL without addition macro like this:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

show{ reify{
  for {
    x <- new A
    y <- new A
  } yield x == y
}.tree }
// new $read.A().flatMap(((x) => new $read.A().map(((y) => x.$eq$eq(y)))))
```

Comment: @TravisBrown: thank you, fixed. I should get some rest.

Comment: +1 for the concise, direct answer (as compared to mine) and reference to -Xprint.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Scala 2.10 or higher, you can use the following to show desugared scala code in the repl:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context // use BlackboxContext if you're in 2.11
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def _desugar(c : Context)(expr : c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._
  println(show(expr.tree))
  reify {}
}

def desugar(expr : Any): Unit = macro _desugar
```

This will allow you to pass in blocks of code, and see what they translate into. For your example, in the repl:

```
scala> class A {
     |   def getInt: Int = throw new RuntimeException
     |   def map(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(getInt)
     |   def flatMap(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(getInt)
     | }
defined class A

scala> desugar {
     |   for {
     |     x <- new A
     |     y <- new A
     |   } yield x == y
     | }
new $line15.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.A().flatMap(((x: Int) => new $line15.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.A().map(((y: Int) => x.==(y)))))
```

It's a bit messy, because the repl creates several intermediate temporary variables, but you can see the structure of what's happening.

```
new A().flatMap { (x: Int) =>
  new A().map { (y: Int) =>
    x == y
  }
}
```

This works for most any expression, and lets you inspect what the actual code will translate to during compilation.

#### Update

I should point out my source - my version of `desugar` is a slightly modified version of a function found in the [Macrocosm](https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala) repo on github.

Comment: Even easier: `scala> reflect.runtime.universe.reify { for (x <- Nil) yield x }
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[Nothing]] = Expr[List[Nothing]](Nil.map(((x) => x))(List.canBuildFrom))`

Comment: This is an awesome (and wholly unexpected) answer - 10/10